# Chrome "stalls" request for about a minute

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, php, hhvm

I am running an NGINX 1.2.1 with HHVM 3.5.0 in FastCGI Mode.

As the title says, Chrome "stalls" the request for a long time after I do the following:

- Open up my website (takes just about 1.5 seconds)
- Wait for ~ 2 minutes
- Click on **another** link on the menu
- Go get yourself a cup of coffee and wait a bit

I reproduced this on IE 11, Firefox and Chrome for Android:

- IE 11: No stalling, no problems, blazing fast
- Firefox: Same as Chrome
- Chrome for Android (OnePlus One): No stalling, no problems, blazing fast

I am convinced, that my server isn't configured wrong since it works on other browsers.

Any help or tips are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: When this occurs the times of the connections are like [this image](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/resultate/uploads/stalled.png) ?

Comment: It's a high-traffic server?

Comment: can you reset the settings for chrome?

Comment: When IE is referred to as having "no problems" and being "blazing fast", there is definitely an issue!   On a serious note, what version of chrome are you running?

Comment: @sergen do you have a solution to the issue you faced ? We are also facing a very similar issue

Answer (score 0):

On the website (while using Chrome), go into developer mode, by right clicking on a blank spot and choosing `Inspect element`

On the top tab, choose Network and this will show you what is taking so long to load.
There is an option there to disable the cache as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling stuff like firebug by uninstalling it.